# Performing asynchronous actions with parameters mobx-state-tree

Tags: javascript, reactjs, asynchronous, action, mobx-state-tree

Using mobx-state-tree I want to pass in parameters to an asynchronous action. They recommend to use generator functions. Their examples does not supply examples using parameters, and I don't find it obvious how to.

I have tried wrapping the flow function inside a normal function to pass the parameters down. However it does not work. I have tried examples below including some additional fiddling.

```
setAvailability: function (id, status) {
        console.log("inside outer")
        flow(function* () {
            console.log("inside inner")
            try {
                yield UpdateAvailability(id, status)
                const { data } = yield self.fetch(GetTutors)
                self.data = data;
            } catch (e) {
                console.log(e.stack)
            }
        })
    },
```

---

```
setAvailability: flow*(function(id, status) {
            console.log("inside inner")
            try {
                yield UpdateAvailability(id, status)
                const { data } = yield self.fetch(GetTutors)
                self.data = data;
            } catch (e) {
                console.log(e.stack)
            }
        })
    },
```

When passing parameters inside the flow function it doesn't compile and when I wrap the function it only prints 
`console.log("inside inner")`

How can I pass parameters to an asynchronous action function?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

I tried a simple example as follows and it works -

```
import {flow, types} from "mobx-state-tree"

const Store = types.model({})
    .actions(self => ({
        fetchProjects: flow(function* fetchProjects(par1, par2) { // <- note the star, this a generator function!
            console.log('flow called');
            console.log(par1);
            console.log(par2);
        })
    }));

export const store = Store.create({});
// async actions will always return a promise resolving to the returned value
store.fetchProjects('test parameter', 'test parameter 2').then(() => {
    console.log("done")
});
```

I think its just the * at the wrong place in your second example.

Comment: Would upvote, however I do not have enough points. Thanks for your answer :)